# bash + find specific word in space-delimited string

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, awk, sed

The parameter `list` include the following example values

```
# echo $list
master01.montil131.com worker01.montil131.com worker02.montil131.com
```

In order to find the word that include `master` string I do the following

```
list=$( for i in ` echo  $list `; do [[ $i =~ master ]] && echo $i ; done )

echo $list
master01.montil131.com
```

but this approach to find the string with `master` word isn't  elegant way

Any other suggestion how to find specific word in `list` ?

Comment: is `$list` a variable that contains the string "master01.montil131.com worker01.montil131.com worker02.montil131.com" ? a space separated list of words stored in a variable?

Comment: just one space between words ( no other comma separator )'

Comment: Unrelated: Why do you store a list in a string? It would be better to have it in an array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use simple `grep` command, I am assuming there are no spaces in a word in the list.

```
 echo $list | tr ' ' '\n' | grep master
```

It will replace space with new line and will then grep word master.

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep -o`:

```
grep -o "[^ ]*master[^ ]*" <<<"$list"
```

If you know that you always have just `master*` and `worker*`, you can use Shell methods:

```
echo "${list// *worker[^ ]*/}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -ow 'master[^ ]*' <<<"$list"
```

or, with GNU `grep`,

```
grep -Pow 'master\S+' <<<"$list"
```

The `-o` would extract the matching bit of the string in `$list`, and `-w` would ensure that we don't match `themaster` or some other word that does not start with `master`.

The `\S` in the second command is a PCRE that will match any non-space character.